# Change to polar coordinates and integrate.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Find the integral
$$\int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}} ~dx \int_3^{2 + \sqrt{4-x^2}} \frac{~dy}{(x^2 + y^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$
by changing to polar coordinates.

I've managed to find the polar coordinates. The area is a circle segment parametrized by
$$x = r \cos \theta, y = 2 + r \sin \theta, \theta \in \left[\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{5 \pi}{6}\right], r \in \left[\frac{1}{\cos \theta}, 2\right].$$
The problem I have is that integrating this expression with this substitution is practically impossible - what am I doing wrong??

Is there any other substitution with polar coordinates I can use? Because I really don't believe that this integration is intended.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: Do not use shifted polar coordinates. Use usual polar coordinates and note that the circle is centered at $(0,2)$ and has radius $2$. This is, of course, $r=4\sin\theta$. Can you finish now?

Comment: Hm, I've never seen this parametrisation before! I'm not sure how does it work, what would be the limits?

Comment: Off-center circles passing through the origin should be in your bag of tricks, centered on either axis. You can derive it either with trig or directly from the cartesian equation. Edit with your modified attempts and let me know where you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very useful and I don't know why I haven't heard about this parametrisation. I've finally managed to solve the problem!